# Trying to prove that a function is bilinear.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, functions

I am following some notes and need a clarification, here is the problematic phrase:

Given a linear function $B: V \rightarrow V^*$ a bilinear function $b: V \times V \rightarrow K$ is implicitly defined by $b(v,w) = (B(w)) (v)$

Now I would like to prove that $b(v,w)$ is indeed bilinear by I am unsure on how to proceed given the definition of $b$.

Is $B((w))(v_1 + v_2) = (B(w))(v_1) + (B(w))(v_2)$ from the fact that $B$ is linear?
Also does $(B(w)) (v)$ means that we apply $B$ to $w$ and then to $v$? buy how are we sure that $B(w)$ does not exit $V$ and the function becomes undefined?

Comment: Since $B\colon V\to V^\ast$, and since $w\in V$, $B(w)\in V^\ast$, which means $B(w)$ is a linear functional on $V$, that is $B(w)\colon V\to K$. So $B(w)$ is not in $V$, but is a linear transformation sending $V$ to the scalar field. So you can apply $B(w)$ to elements $v\in V$ as you would with any linear transformation with domain $V$.

Comment: Sometimes (and probably in this case) it is more clear to write $B_w = B(w)$ so that it is obvious that it is a transformation.

Comment: Is $V^*$ the dual space of $V?$ If so, then linearity of $b$ in the first variable follows from the fact that $B(w)$ belongs to $V^{*},$ and thus is a linear map (with domain $V$). Linearity of $b$ in the second variable appears to follow by applying linearity of $B$ followed by pointwise defined addition of functionals in $V^{*}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$B$ is a map from $V$ to $V^*$, i.e. it maps every $w \in V$ to a (linear) map from $V$ to $\mathbb{R}$. This means that $B(w)$ is actually a *function*; More precisely $(B(w))( \cdot) : V \to \mathbb{R}$ is a linear map.

Comment: So because $B(w)$ is a liner map I get one condition for bilinearity, namely $B((w))(v_1 + v_2) = (B(w))(v_1) + (B(w))(v_2)$. But what about $(B(w_1 + w_2))(v) = B(w_1)(v) + B(w_2)(v)$?

Comment: Note that $B$ is a linear map from $V$ to $V^*$.